# python extract data from textfile

Tags: python

i am new to python and need help. i want to extract data from a textfile and dont know exatcly how to handle it the right way.

*sample.txt*

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
data('unimportant', 'unimportant2');    
data('user', 'Marcus');
data('fullname', 'Marcus Dwony');
data('birthday', '14.05.1981');
data('unimportant3', 'unimportant4');
data('unimportant5', 'unimportant6');
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
```

i want to extract the `data('SOME1','VALUE1');` fields and store the values to new variables named user, fullname and birthday.

i try it with regex. but dont know how to extract the fields.

```
import re

with open ("sample.txt") as f_in:       
    for line in f_in:
        if re.match(r"data\(\'(user|fullname|birthday)", line):
            print(line)
```

thx for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
>>> f = open('your_file.txt')
>>> for x in f:
...     k = re.search(r"'(user|fullname|birthday)', '(.*)'", x)
...     if  k:
...         print "{} {}".format(k.group(1), k.group(2))
... 
user Marcus
fullname Marcus Dwony
birthday 14.05.1981
```

Note `match` matches from the start of string, but `search` can match anywere in the string

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex so that you have a group corresponding to the value of the data.

```
"data\('(user|fullname|birthday)',\s+'([!']+)'\)"
```

Retain a reference to the value returned from `re.match`: it is a [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject). You can extract the second group from this:

```
match = re.match(r"data\('(user|fullname|birthday)',\s+'([^']+)'\)", line)
if (not(match is None)):
    print(match.group(2)
```

While this is one way to solve the problem, I strongly recommend that you use one of the innumerable convenient, well defined, easy to use data formats that are already out there, like JSON or YAML or whatever suits your fancy. This way you don't have to debug your serialization/deserialization code; you can just drop in a proven third party library to handle it. Less headaches all around.

Comment: thx for the nice explantation and your recommendation. can you tell me how can i parse this txt.file into json ??

Comment: @user4386249 Your JSON file would look something like [this](https://gist.github.com/masaeedu/49e08bfc5d79b3bd8681). You'd then be able to get an object representing all of your data using a JSON deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:data|-)\(\'(user|fullname|birthday)+\', \'(.*?)+\'\);
```

This regex should work. http://www.regexr.com/3ab40

This will match but won't capture "data" string: `(?:data|-)`

This means everything between quotes: `\'(.*?)+\'`

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in lines:
    m = re.match(r'^data\s*\(\s*\'(user|fullname|birthday)\'\s*,\s*\'(.*)\'\s*\)\s*;$', line.strip())
    if m:
        print m.groups()
```

This solution handles spaces inside/outside braces.